# Login Modal view not showing over a splitview

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, loginview

I have been looking for some code that will show a Login Modal window first before it loads the other views.

I created a Login nib, and in the applicationDidFinishLaunching appdelegate i use this code:

```
    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    IntroView *introViewController=[[[IntroView alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroView" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [introViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen] ;
    [self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:introViewController animated:NO];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
...
```

When running this, the modal window doesn't show but it gets loaded when i NSLog it.
Any idea why it is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

My app starts with a split view and opens a modal login window if there is no active session (defined in a core data entity).
Add the viewDidAppear method to your initial detail view controller.
Create a modal segue to a new login view controller.
Do login stuff in the login view and then dismiss it with "[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];"

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated<br>

{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Check if a existing session is open, if not the login screen will appear.
    // When user logs on an open session record is added to the table.  Closed on user logout.

    userProfile = [LogonSessionManager getCurrentPtuser:managedObjectContext];
    if(userProfile == nil){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self]; 
    } else {
        // We have a user - do user config display stuff
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@greentor: Your answer is not fully correct. The correct modal segue should be from the main SplitView. That means you have to call in your DetailViewController#viewDidAppear:

```
[self.splitViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self.splitViewController];
```

Comment: so how do you dismiss the loginviewcontroller after successfully loggin in?